# Подскажите что не так делаю

Tags: simple-html-dom, php

Пытаюсь найти все текстовые узлы в элементе и выдает ошибку.
    Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 19

```
$array = $log->find('font[class=B9]')->find('text');

<font class='B9'><font class='B1'><img src=http://img.combats.ru/i/align11.gif width=12 height=15><img src=http://img.combats.ru/i/klan/WoF.gif width=24 height=15>МАДРА</font></font></br><font class='B9'><font class='B2'><img src=http://img.combats.ru/i/align25.gif width=12 height=15><img src=http://img.combats.ru/i/klan/AzureDragons.gif width=24 height=15>Левий Матвей</font></font></br>
```

Comment: кавычек нет у некоторых атрибутов, <br> не правильный, вы в общем не html пытаетесь парсить.

Comment: тоеть все дело в ковычках?

Comment: html конечно не правильный, но этой библиотеке все равно. На первой странице написано что Supports invalid HTML.

Comment: @abibock_un до какой степени invalid html ? вот такое будет работать ?

    <div class="test" content</div> 

?

у него закрывающий тег без открытия.

Comment: До какой степени - это вопрос не ко мне =), а к разработчикам. Тут бесспорно Ваша правда, что не стоит никому доверять, в писать валидный html. Но в данном случае его строчка нармально проходит

$string ='html из вопроса';
$html = str_get_html($string);
print $html->find('font[class=B9]',0)->find('text',0);

Comment: С индексами разобрался,а как найти все узлы?

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, Вам нужно указать индекс в методе find, т.к. Вы вызываете этот метод уже в обьекте, где нет никаких css секторов.

```
$log->find('font[class=B9]',0)->find('text',0);
```

Это описанно в документации

> find ( string $selector [, int $index] )  Find children by the CSS selector. **Returns the Nth element object** if index is set, otherwise, return an array of object.

[Документацию можно найти здесь](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = $log->find('font.B9 font');

    for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++){
        echo $matches[$i]->find('text',0)."<br>";
    }
```

решил вот таким путем,если можно иначе как то,просьба отписаться

Answer (score 0):

Я увеличила в simple_html_dom.php `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000)`, согласно вот этой [статье](http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object.html).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Такое значение изначально там есть.